# Sparse Efficiency Warning while changing the column

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nlp

```
def tdm_modify(feature_names,tdm):
    non_useful_words=['kill','stampede','trigger','cause','death','hospital'\
        ,'minister','said','told','say','injury','victim','report']
    indexes=[feature_names.index(word) for word in non_useful_words]
    for index in indexes:
        tdm[:,index]=0   
    return tdm
```

I want to manually set zero weights for some terms in tdm matrix. Using the above code I get the warning. I don't seem to understand why? Is there a better way to do this?

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py:730: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, it is not an error.  It's a warning.  The next time you perform this action (in a session) it will do it without warning.

To me the message is clear:

```
Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. 
lil_matrix is more efficient.
```

`tdm` is a `csr_matrix`.  The way that data is stored with the format, it takes quite a bit of extra computation to set a bunch of the elements to 0 (or v.v to change them from 0).  As it says, the `lil_matrix` format is better if you need to do this sort of change frequently.

Try some time tests on a sample matrices.  `tdm.tolil()` will convert the matrix to `lil` format.

I could get into how the data is stored and why changing `csr` is less efficient than `lil`.

I'd suggest reviewing the `sparse` formats, and their respective pros and cons.

A simple way to think about is - `csr` (and `csc`) are designed for fast numerical calculations, especially matrix multiplication.  They developed for linear algebra problems.  `coo` is a convenient way of defining sparse matrices.  `lil` is a convenient way for building matrices incrementally.

How are you constructing `tdm` initially?

---

In `scipy` test files (e.g. `scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/tests/test_linsolve.py`) I find code that does

```
import warnings
from scipy.sparse import (spdiags, SparseEfficiencyWarning, csc_matrix,
    csr_matrix, isspmatrix, dok_matrix, lil_matrix, bsr_matrix)
warnings.simplefilter('ignore',SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

scipy/sparse/base.py

```
class SparseWarning(Warning):
    pass
class SparseFormatWarning(SparseWarning):
    pass
class SparseEfficiencyWarning(SparseWarning):
    pass
```

These warnings use the standard Python `Warning` class, so standard Python methods for controlling their expression apply.

Comment: How can I disable this warning? I am running a script, and this message gets printed to stdout. This is very annoying, because then I have to parse it out to get the results I want.

Comment: If there is any scipy developer around, I really think this message should be in the documentation. It should not be printed to console, not even once.

Comment: I've looked up some options for suppressing warnings.

Comment: Have you considered changing the script so it doesn't issue this warning - for example by changing the sparse format.  The warning is there for a reason.  It pays to heed it.

Comment: The other formats don't let me change a value. I am only doing this once in the script, so performance is not a problem.

Comment: 'coo'doesn't allow the element indexing; but `lil` should allow it.  But for one such assignment, it wouldn't be wroth the conversion time.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this warning message as well working on a machine learning problem.  The exact application was constructing a document term matrix from a corpus of text.  I agree with the accepted answer.  I will add one empirical observation:

My exact task was to build a 25000 x 90000 matrix of uint8.
My desired output was a sparse matrix compressed row format, i.e. csr_matrix.

The fastest way to do this by far, at the cost of using quite a bit more memory in the interim, was to initialize a dense matrix using np.zeros(), build it up, then do csr_matrix(dense_matrix) once at the end.

The second fastest way was to build up a lil_matrix, then convert it to csr_matrix with the .tocsr() method.  This is recommended in the accepted answer.  (Thank you hpaulj).

The slowest way was to assemble the csr_matrix element by element.

So to sum up, if you have enough working memory to build a dense matrix, and only want to end up with a sparse matrix later on for downstream efficiency, it might be faster to build up the matrix in dense format and then covert it once at the end.  If you need to work in sparse format the whole time because of memory limitations, building up the matrix as a lil_matrix and then converting it (as in the accepted answer) is faster than building up a csr_matrix from the start.

Comment: Actually @hpaulj did not mention `.tocsr()`.