# Python scipy.sparse: how to efficiently set a set of entries to 0?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Let `a` be a big `scipy.sparse` matrix and IJ={(i0,j0),(i1,j1),...} a set of positions. How can I efficiently set all the entries in `a` in positions `IJ` to 0? Something like `a[IJ]=0`.

In Mathematica, I would create a new sparse matrix `b` with background value 1 (instead of 0) and all entries in `IJ`. Then, I would use `a=a*b` (entry-wise multiplication). That does not seem to be an option here.

A toy example:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=200,edgeitems=5,precision=4)
m=n=10**1;
a=sp.random(m,n,4/m,format='csr'); print(a.toarray())
IJ=np.array([range(0,n,2),range(0,n,2)]); print(IJ) #every second diagonal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. To go by your definitions, all you'd need to do is:

```
a[IJ[0],IJ[1]] = 0
```

Note that scipy will warn you:

> SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.

You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091397/sparse-efficiency-warning-while-changing-the-column).

Comment: Aaah, you're right. I thought that operation would set all IJ[0]-rows and IJ[1]-columns to 0, not individual entries with those coordinates. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to make this warning not appear in one specific call? Like `quiet( a[IJ[0],IJ[1]]=0 )`?

Comment: @Leo I think you best heed the warning and use a different internal matrix storage.  If you really insist you can wrap the offending operation in a `with warnings.catch_warnings():` block.

Answer (score 1):

The scipy sparse matrices can't have a non-zero background value. While it it possible to make a "sparse" matrix with lots of non-zero value, the performance (speed & memory) would be far worse than dense matrix multiplication.

A possible work-around is to rewrite every sparse matrix to have a default value of zero. For example, if matrix `Y'` contains mostly 1, I can replace `Y'` by `I - Y` where `Y = I - Y'` and `I` is the identity matrix.

```py
import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy as np

size = (100, 100)
x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=size)
y = sp.random(*size, 0.001, format='csr')

# Z = (I - Y)X = X - YX
z = x - y.multiply(x)

# A = X(I - Y) = X - XY = X - transpose(YX)
a = x - y.multiply(x).T
```

Comment: How can one specify a different background value in the [dok format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html)?

Comment: Sorry. Probably even dok can't do that. Saw this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.setdefault.html#scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.setdefault but that only provide a function similar to the method of dict.

Comment: I think the underlying blas and lapack don't support non-zero background values. Mathematica probably also use blas and lapack. See the formats at: http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node372.html#sec:data-structures